# Getting a none type error python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, error-handling

```
#Creates a new Node 
#nextnode acts as a pointer    
class Node(object):
        def __init__(self,data):
            self.data = data
            self.nextnode = None
    class LinkedList(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.head = None
            self.size =0
    #Insertion
Adding elements at start and end of linked list

        def insertStart(self,data):
            self.size+=1
            newnode = Node(data)
            if not self.head:
                self.head = newnode
            else:
                newnode.nextnode = self.head
                self.head = newnode
        def size(self):
            return self.size



        def insertEnd(self,data):
            self.size+=1
            newnode = Node(data)
            actualnode = self.head
            while actualnode is not None:
                actualnode = actualnode.nextnode #Eroor here!!!!
            actualnode.nextnode = newnode

         #Traversing through linked list
        def traverse(self):
            actualnode = self.head
            while actualnode is not None:
                print("Actual Node {}".format(actualnode.data))
                actualnode = actualnode.nextnode

    #Removing node
        def remove(self,data):
            if (self.head == None):
                return
            currentnode = self.head
            previousnode = None
            while (currentnode.data != data):
                previousnode = currentnode
                currentnode = currentnode.nextnode
            if previousnode is None:
                self.head = currentnode.nextnode
            else:
                previousnode.nextnode = currentnode.nextnode

    linkedlist = LinkedList()
    linkedlist.insertStart(12)
    linkedlist.insertStart(13)
    linkedlist.insertStart(14)
    linkedlist.insertStart(15)
    linkedlist.insertEnd(16)
    linkedlist.traverse()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Could you describe your issue in more details and provide an example of how to run your code to reproduce the error that (only you so far) see?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `insertEnd`, you're guaranteeing you always have `None` for `actualnode` at the end of the loop:

```
def insertEnd(self, data):
    self.size += 1
    newnode = Node(data)
    actualnode = self.head

    # Keep going until actualnode is None
    while actualnode is not None:
        actualnode = actualnode.nextnode

    # Here actualnode will always be None
    actualnode.nextnode = newnode
```

To fix this, just change your while loop condition:

```
while actualnode.nextnode is not None:
    actualnode = actualnode.nextnode
```

Note that this assumes `self.head` is always non-`None`. You should probably explicitly check for this condition. Maybe something like this:

```
def insertEnd(self, data):
    self.size += 1
    newnode = Node(data)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = newnode
    else:
        actualnode = self.head
        while actualnode.nextnode is not None:
            actualnode = actualnode.nextnode
        actualnode.nextnode = newnode
```